# Crystal Reports: Display Subdetail Section Without Repeat Detailt Section

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm doing a report using Crystal Report in VB.NET. I'm using 4 tables, and I want to display user information with a list of actions/permissions for every user, but my report
is displaying the user data with one record from his action, the same user data and another record of his actios, like this:

```
Last Name    First Name   Occupation
Doe          John         Student
Record some data         16/12/2013
Doe          John         Student
Record some data         17/12/2013
Doe          John         Student
Erase data               18/12/2013
Doe          John         Student
Print data               19/12/2013
Xavier       Professor    Master
Erase data               21/12/2013
Xavier       Professor    Master
Record some data         21/12/2013
```

But what I want its this:

```
Last Name    First Name   Occupation
Doe          John         Student
Record some data         16/12/2013
Record some data         17/12/2013
Erase data               18/12/2013
Print data               19/12/2013

Xavier       Professor    Master
Erase data               21/12/2013
Record some data         21/12/2013
```

If I put user data with action data at the same DetailSection, my user data is repeated with every action from the user, but I want just one time the user data, and then all his actions
Also, If i put the user data in the PageHeaderSection with the titles, my user data is displayed at the header, and the all his actions, but when an user data is finished, it does not print the next user data and his actions. It prints the actions of the next user, and the user data is displayed until the next page...

Answer (score 0):

How you are going to distinguish students with the same name ?
Put the user data in the details section but add grouping by a unique field (or a formula , which combines few fields).

Comment: My users data its in one table, actions its in another table (the action's ID and date), and names of the actions (ID and Description) its in another table. That's why my user data is repeated from every action

Comment: You can create a formula to combine Last Name, First Name and Occupation. The group by this formula and place those fields in the group section and all the other fields on the details section. This will resolve your current problem but you might face another one - when you have 2 students with the same first and last name. Then the actions for those students will be grouped together. Check your database structure and find an unique filed , which identified the student - then use this field to group and place the fields as describred above

Answer (score 0):

Group by user and put actions in detail section.